# How to solve Zabbix database is not available

Tags: postgresql

I received the following db message from Zabbix server.
It seemed it was a temporary issue because currently db is accessible and postgresql service is in "running" state.
This message detects about once per a half-year.
Could you advise what causes the message and how to solve the issue?

The Postgresql version is 10.18.

```
PostgreSQL database "zabbix" on "localhost:5432" is not available: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

`/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log.1` showed as below:

```
2022-05-25 21:55:11.148 UTC [29934] zabbix@zabbix FATAL: the database system is shutting down
2022-05-25 21:55:11.154 UTC [9362] zabbix@zabbix FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command
2022-05-25 21:55:11.302 UTC [9312] LOG: shutting down
2022-05-25 21:55:11.446 UTC [9310] LOG: database system is shut down
2022-05-25 21:56:28.579 UTC [30183] LOG: listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2022-05-25 21:56:28.617 UTC [30183] LOG: listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-05-25 21:56:28.816 UTC [30188] LOG: database system was shut down at 2022-05-25 21:55:11 UTC
2022-05-25 21:56:28.831 UTC [30189] zabbix@zabbix FATAL: the database system is starting up
2022-05-25 21:56:28.862 UTC [30183] LOG: database system is ready to accept connections
2022-05-25 21:56:29.420 UTC [30202] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG: incomplete startup packet
2022-05-25 21:56:29.940 UTC [30227] postgres@postgres FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2022-05-25 21:56:29.940 UTC [30227] postgres@postgres DETAIL: Password does not match for user "postgres".
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 85: "local all postgres md5"
2022-05-25 21:56:35.154 UTC [30286] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG: incomplete startup packet
```

Comment: Well, it was commanded to shut down, and started back up 1 minute 13 seconds later ... perhaps the system rebooted for an OS patch?

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
I corrected the version info above.
Actually, this server did not have "manually-rebooted" history (like applying patches) at the time of the issue.

Comment: I found the following link regarding "terminating connection due to administrator command" seen in the log.

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/5665.1202148155%40sss.pgh.pa.us#:~:text=Re%3A%20PGSQL%20ERROR%3A%20FATAL%3A%20terminating%20connection%20due%20to%20administrator%20command,-From%3A&text=This%20means%20that%20something%20sent%20the%20server%20process%20a%20SIGTERM%20signal.&text=not%20what's%20happening%20because%20the%20postmaster%20must%20still%20be%20there.&text=window%20are%20causing%20it.

Comment: However, I wonder if it is directly in relation to the cause or not.
If you give me any other perspective where to check next time, that's really appreciated.

Comment: How should we know who or what shuts down your database?

Comment: I have no idea of this db shutdown. That's why I wonder anyone here has ever seen this and is well familiar with this kind of message.